# How can I disable the save credit card info popup in the chrome on Android device?

Tags: javascript, selenium, popup

I am try to run some automation scripts writing with WD.js on the lamda cloud server,but I can not handle this popup,any suggestions?Thanks so much!

Here is my capabilities setting,but it seems not work.

```
  exports.config = {
  seleniumHost: 'hub.lambdatest.com',
  seleniumPort: 80,
  test: '../tests/demo.js',
  capabilities: [{
        build: "test demo",
        name: "work flow",
        platform: "Android",
        deviceName: "Huawei P20 Pro",
        platformVersion: "9",
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        visual: "true",
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          prefs: {
            credentials_enable_service: false,
            'profile.password_manager_enabled': false,
            'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': '2'
        },
         args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors',
           '--disable-features=Translate',
           '--disable-popup-blocking',
           '--disable-notifications',
           '-incognito']
    }
    }]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a feature provided by Chrome itself. Have you tried `chrome://settings/payments` Save and Fill Payment Methods?

Comment: Try adding autocomplete="off" to any field that you don't want completing automatically.

Comment: Actually this page is a confirmation page after I submit the credit card info,there are not any input fields on this page,I just think is there anyway to disable this popup in the capabilities?Or can I handle this popup by click 'No thanks' button to close it?Because I want to click the 'Next Step' button which was covered by this popup.Thanks again.